# TinyMCE adding toggle style

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm working on a TinyMCE plugin and one thing I want it to do is register commands/buttons that toggle custom formatting.

For example if you click the bold button in TinyMCE it will show the bold button highlighted while in bold text. Digging into the source code I see this happens via:  tinymce.EditorCommands.addCommands thought I can't seem to figure out how to duplicate it. The documentation of TinyMCE is just horrible as well =(

So given customFormat I want to be able to have a button setup by my plugin that when the customFormat is applied it shows as such like the Bold, Italics, and other such buttons do on the toolbar. And clicking on my customFormat toggles that format on/off. I can easily accomplish the toogle via "addCommand" and "addButton" but then it does not have state tracking like Bold and others do.

Showing my current non-working attempt (this code is inside init of my plugin create method):

```
tinymce.EditorCommands.call('addCommands', {
   'MyFormat' :  function(name) {
      ed.formatter.toggle("customFormat");
    }
},'exec');

tinymce.EditorCommands.call('addCommands', {
   'MyFormat' : function(name) {
       return ed.formatter.match('customFormat');
    } 
},'state');

ed.addButton('customformat', {cmd : 'MyFormat'});
```

And here is the link to the "documentation" of addCommands:
http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.EditorCommands.addCommands

After a lot more looking around I found this which seems to be perfect:
http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.addQueryStateHandler

But when I implement the code it doesn't change the state of the button:

```
  ed.addCommand('MyFormat', function(ui, v) {
    ed.formatter.toggle("thoughtFormat");
  });

  ed.addQueryStateHandler('MyFormat', function() { 
      return ed.formatter.match('thoughtFormat');
  });

  ed.addButton('myformat', {cmd : 'MyFormat'});
```

Comment: have a look at controlmanager and the flag active/ the function setActive

Comment: I'll look. Appreciate the tip. Though the documentation of TinyMCE is pretty bad so if you happen to have any examples or links that help please let me know.

Comment: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:class.tinymce.ControlManager

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In case someone doesn't want to do it the 'plug-in' way, here's the guide for `TinyMCE 4.x`.

First of all, you need to define a custom format:

```
formats: {
   custom_format: {inline: 'span', styles: {color: "red"}, attributes: {class: 'some_css_class'}}
}
```

Then you'll have to add a button to your toolbar:

```
toolbar: "mybutton",
```

Next, you need to setup your button, so that it toggles the format:

```
setup: function(editor) {
        editor.addButton('mybutton', {
            text: 'My button',
            icon: false,
            onclick: function() {
                tinymce.activeEditor.formatter.toggle('custom_format')
            }
        });
}
```

Furthermore, if you want the editor to set the state of the button to indicate the format of current node, automatically, add this to `setup` function:

```
onPostRender: function() {
    var ctrl = this;                
    editor.on('NodeChange', function(e) {
        ctrl.active(e.element.className == "some_css_class")
    });
}
```

Your `tinymce.init` function should look like this:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    formats: {
       // Other formats...
       custom_format: {inline: 'span', styles: {color: "red"}, attributes: {class: 'some_css_class'}}
    }
    // Other default toolbars
    toolbar_n: "mybutton",

    // Finally, setup your button
    setup: function(editor) {
        editor.addButton('mybutton', {
            text: 'My Button',
            icon: false,
            onclick: function() {
                tinymce.activeEditor.formatter.toggle('custom_format')
            },
            onPostRender: function() {
                var ctrl = this;                
                editor.on('NodeChange', function(e) {
                    ctrl.active(e.element.className == "some_css_class")
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Note that `class` attribute I added to my custom format. This approach made it possible for me define my custom styles in a separate stylesheet file and keep my markup as dry as possible (No inline styling!). Point `content_css` option to your stylesheet and you'll be good to go.
However, due to fact that I'm using Rails as back-end and BatmanJS as front-end (and I'm fairly new to the latter), I couldn't figure out how assets routing works, and ended up adding my custom styles to default content stylesheet file of tinyMCE skin itself (located at `skins/SKIN_NAME/content.min.css`).

Comment: very nice answer, thanks!
One little mistake: you have to use `styles:{color: "red"}` (note the **s**) to get the red font color ;)

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to Thariama for insights that allowed me to dig deeper finally figuring out how to do this. I'm not sure its the "right way" but as I said TinyMCE has the worst documentation imaginable.

The key for me was to make an hook the onNodeChange event, using the setActive trick. Full example plugin with a custom button that activates when that format is present wherever the cursor is:

```
(function() {
   tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.CoolPlugin', {  
   init : function(ed, url) {   

      ed.addCommand('MyFormat', function(ui, v) {
        ed.formatter.toggle("myFormat");
      });

      ed.addButton("coolformat", {
        title : 'MyFormat Tooltip', 
        cmd : 'MyFormat',
        image: url + '/coolformat.png',
      });

      ed.onNodeChange.add(function(ed, cm, n) {
        active = ed.formatter.match('myFormat');
        control = ed.controlManager.get('coolformat').setActive(active);
      });

      ed.onInit.add(function(ed, e) {
        ed.formatter.register('myFormat', 
           {inline: 'span', classes : ['cool'] } );
      });
  }
  });

  // Register plugin
  tinymce.PluginManager.add('cool', tinymce.plugins.CoolPlugin);
})();
```

Comment: Update: not anymore, since TinyMCE has upgraded to 4.x some of these methods have been deprecated.

Comment: What's this 
```
ed.onNodeChange.add(function(ed, cm, n) {
        active = ed.formatter.match('myFormat');
        control = ed.controlManager.get('coolformat').setActive(active);
      });
```
equivalent on 4.x onwards now ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
ed.controlManager.get('my_control_element').setActive(true); // could be bold or whatever
```

Comment: controlManager is not defined under ed in the plug. So this code raises an exception. I'm updating my answer with another thing I found as well.

Comment: well, you will need to have the editor instace ed. you can get one by var ed = tinymce.get('your_editorid');

Comment: Yes, ed is defined already in the plugin. But controlManger isn't defined within ed.

Comment: it should be, at least when the editor instance has been initialized - not before then

Comment: Thanks! Put the code inside ed.OnInit but now it just shows as active all the time. It isn't updating when I click on non-formatted text like Bold does, etc.

Comment: you ned to take care of the activating/deactivatiob yourself unfortunatly. use setactive(0) fot this